# Check to see if current url matches string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to see if a link to the current page's URL exists in a menu.

```
var thisUrl = window.location.href;

$("ul.leftmenu li a").each(function() { 

  var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');

  if (thisUrl === thisHref) { 

    // matches

  }

});
```

This works as long as the current window location URL does not contain any _GET variables. How would I modify this to ignore the _GET variables in the current address?

Comment: Instead of `thisUrl` use a substring of `thisUrl` until the first `?`

Comment: Check out the match function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Why dont you use regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove query string part from the `href`. For example like this:

```
var thisUrl = window.location.href.replace(location.search, '');
```

`location.search` property represents GET parameters substring, i.e. `?param=value&param2=etc`.

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. Will accept answer as soon as I'm able.

Comment: I also noticed that it will break if there is an `#` at the end of the url. Is there any way to filter this out as well?

Comment: Well you can also remove hash part: `window.location.href.replace(location.search, '').replace(location.hash, '')`. But if there is anything else you want to remove then it will be sign that you might want to use regexp.